# How do I offer users to point their domain on their account application subdomain, created over my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an multi-tenancy application on Ruby on Rails, I offer application to users that can be created over my website. They use sub-domain to access their account. I want to give them facility to park or point their domain to their account sub-domain. I want this setting to be created over my website in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

**Set Up Your CNAME Record.**

Below are instructions for updating the CNAME record for your domain.

Go to your registrar (or hosting provider if you have changed the nameservers to them)

Find your DNS settings

Follow the instructions to point the CNAME record (sub-domain) for your domain.

Point the desired subdomain to Your Domain

Propagation of subdomain may take upto 24 - 48 hours.

Than in your controller, you can access the original domain URL by `request.original_url` and according to that URL you can show your users specific pages.